# Call mySQL procedure c#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have procedure, which works good in MySQL Workbench:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dane dla stacji`(IN naz varchar(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT stacje.nazwa, parametry.nazwa, wyniki_pomiarow.wartosc, wyniki_pomiarow.data 
    FROM srodowisko.stacje, srodowisko.parametry, srodowisko.wyniki_pomiarow 
    WHERE stacje.nazwa=naz AND stacje.idStacji = wyniki_pomiarow.idStacji AND parametry.idParametru = wyniki_pomiarow.idParametru;
END
```

Now i would like to call it in c# and display in dataGrid. I wrote something like that:

```
public void display(string zapytanie_sql)
        {         
mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=***");
                mcon.Open();;
                mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(zapytanie_sql, mcon);
                ds = new DataSet();
                mda.Fill(ds, "stacje");
            }

        public void doCommand(string komenda_sql)
        {
            mcon = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=***");
                mcon.Open();;
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(komenda_sql, mcon);
            MySqlDataReader reader;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //while (reader.Read()) { }
            mcon.Close();            
        }
```

When I use simple Query it works, but with procedure it doesn't.

```
            zapytanie_sql = "call srodowisko.`dane dla stacji`('Olkusz');";
            baza.display(zapytanie_sql);
```

Comment: procedure doesn't accept white space

Comment: command.CommandType  = CommandType.StoredProcedure is missing. I think so

Comment: Ok, now it works, simple mistake white spaces! Thank you!